# Convert Date from String in server

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Hi am getting date from server like "2013-11-18T13:21:51" format and trying to set date format to get date from string but it always showing null.

```
-(NSString*)convertStringToDate:(NSString*)fromdate
{

    // CreatedDateTime = "2013-11-18T13:21:51";

    NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate * from = [formatter dateFromString:fromdate];

    NSLog(@"date  %@  ",from);    

    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
   [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

    NSLog(@"date string  %@  ",[df stringFromDate:from]);

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:from]];
}
```

Please correct me where am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

`[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"]`;

With

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It's the wrong year format.

Comment: @rmaddy corrected. Originally written yyyy but replaced again with YYYY as he might need week-based calendar year .